# Remove / Hide border of TTrackBar

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I have a TTrackBar on my form, but would like it to not have the border around it:

[image: Trackbar with Outline Border]

ie. only the blue arrow should be visible - the border (and the content, ie the area that the arrow navigates in) should be invisible (could be solved by setting the color to clBtnFace if need be).

I have tried many things to hide this (in an overridden Create CONSTRUCTOR):

```
BevelEdges:=[];
BevelInner:=TBevelCut.bvNone;
BevelOuter:=TBevelCut.bvNone;
BevelKind:=TBevelKind.bkNone;
BorderWidth:=0;
Brush.Color:=clBtnFace;
ParentCtl3D:=FALSE;
Ctl3D:=FALSE;
```

but it doesn't appear to make any difference.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: It looks like it's using a Windows control, so not everything can be changed. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-trackbar-control-reference-messages) for messages.  Read each one and try anything that looks promising.  Otherwise you will have to find a 3rd party control or roll your own.

Comment: Look at TTrackBar.CNNotify method under TBCD_CHANNEL. Modifying size of R rectangle should have the desired effect. I never tried to completely remove it, I am just painting it 2 pixels in width. I would post the code, but it is entangled with some other custom things and I don't have time now to clear the parts and test.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: I tried setting the rect to the empty rect, and it seems to work.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand if you have working example you can post as answer.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: It seems to me like it is better to simply set `Message.Result := CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT` when you are about to draw the channel, isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can override the track bar's `CNNotify` message method to handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw) notification when `dwDrawStage = CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT` and `dwItemSpec = TBCD_CHANNEL`, setting the result to `CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT`:

```pascal
procedure TTrackBar.CNNotify(var Message: TWMNotifyTRB);
begin

  if
    (Message.NMHdr.code = NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
      and
    (Message.NMCustomDraw.dwDrawStage = CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT)
      and
    (Message.NMCustomDraw.dwItemSpec = TBCD_CHANNEL)
  then
    Message.Result := CDRF_SKIPDEFAULT
  else
    inherited;

end;
```

[image: Screenshot of channel-less track bar control.]

Don't forget to set `ShowSelRange = False` and `TickStyle = tsNone`.

Comment: Egg-cellent. That seems to work...